# 3d graph rotation

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, plot-themes, image3d

I want to rotate the VectorPlote3D of the following

```
VectorPlot3D[{-y, x, z}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, VectorScale -> {Small, 0.6, Automatic}]
```

and also creat GUI to control the rotation speed.

Comment: `rotate the VectorPlote3D` what exactly do you mean by this? Is this similar to when using the mouse to rotate the 3D plot with?

Comment: @Nasser Yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Animate[With[{vp = RotationTransform[theta, {0, 0, 1}][{4, 0, 4}]}, 
  VectorPlot3D[{-y, x, z}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
   VectorScale -> {Small, 0.6, Automatic}, 
   ViewPoint -> vp, 
   SphericalRegion -> True]], 
{theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mathematicain, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.